# Getting JSON value from Azure function

Tags: node.js, json, azure, azure-functions

I want  to fetch data that comes in JSON.

[image]
 Below is the message

```
{"metadata":{..."Records":"Speed;Time","Unit":"m/s;hr",
 "Tag_number":"CWZ;CWD"},
"data":{"Timestamp":"8/1/2019 3:35:50 PM",
"Data_Status":"Good","Speed":0.373,
"Time":0.366210938,"Temperature":23.4375,"ID":"000FFEA3DD"}}
```

I want value of Speed/Temperature/Time depending on what is in metadata Records. Here it is Speed and Time So I want the value of Speed and time that is
that is speed=0.373 and time=0.3662

Answer (score 1):

I test with a HTTP trigger function, the below is my code. If your message is in json format, you could just select the property you want without parsing it.

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

var jsonContent = req.body;
context.res={
    body:"Speed:"+(jsonContent.data.Speed)+"\r\n"+"Time:"+(jsonContent.data.Time)
};
};
```

[image]

From this pic, you cold see the response result. Hope this could help you.

Comment: @Deep Gopal Das, if this could help you, you could accept it as the answer.